# Individual navigation bar for every tabbar item in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbaritem

I need an individual navigation bar for every single tab-bar item because I have different type of titles in each every navigation bar and I need to add some customize buttons on this navigation bar. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new navigation bar for each element of your tab bars.

Look at TweetStation to see how it is done there:

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/Main.cs#L90